# Proxify dns queries at the command-line

Tags: configuration, dns, proxy

I want to use different dns server (not tor, any dns server I set) for certain terminal command.
Say it would looks like

```
$ DNS_SERVER=8.8.8.8 dnsify ping example.com
```

and it uses Google dns.
I know there's socksify, torrify and other tools like that. I look for any tool, hack, or other way I can set it explicitly for my command or at least restricted to terminal session. So I use different dns for my command or in my terminal session, and main dns for all other software.

I tryed proxychains but can't force it to use non-system proxy.

So, is there anything for dns proxifying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any method to override the system resolvers simply by using environment variables. You can override `resolv.conf` options using `RES*` environment variables but those can't be used to override the `nameserver` definitions (see the [`resolv.conf` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) for more information).

The best option would be to use the `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism of the dynamic linker to preload a library that allows you to override the various resolver calls to use your own DNS server rather than the system ones.

One that I've found is [resolvconf-override](https://github.com/hadess/resolvconf-override). From the README:

> resolvconf override provides a shared library to be used as an LD_PRELOAD to override the nameservers listed in /etc/resolv.conf on glibc-based systems (eg. most Linux distributions).
>
> ...
>
> To use the Google DNS in place of the ones mentioned in
>   /etc/resolv.conf you would run:
>   `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libresolvconf-override.so NAMESERVER1=8.8.8.8
>   NAMESERVER2=8.8.4.4 myapplication`

You will need to compile it from source, but it looks to do exactly what you need.

**Note:** You didn't specify an operating system, but I'm assuming Linux.

Comment: Not working in my case (apparently my soft uses gethostbyname2 ) but it's right direction to go, thanks!

Comment: It should be fairly straightforward to extend it to support `gethostbyname2()` as the calls are almost identical.

Comment: Sure, that's what i'll try. However i am very bad at C coding. But you gave me right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[resolv_wrapper](https://cwrap.org/resolv_wrapper.html) from samba project I think does the job well. Allows for a custom `resolv.conf` as well custom DNS records with `RESOLV_WRAPPER_HOSTS`.